# SonarCloud coverage report from create-react-app tests

Tags: sonarqube, create-react-app, lcov

I have a project I'm working on for my senior project. This project was bootstrapped with create-react-app, and I added some config to ensure that coverage reports are generate. I integrated the project with Travis CI, SonarCloud, and Heroku.

I can't figure out how to get SonarCloud to read the lcov file that is generated on the Travis CI build.

Project is here: https://github.com/tanichols/rental-property-calculator
Travis CI build is here: https://travis-ci.org/tanichols/rental-property-calculator
SonarCloud project is here: https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=rental-property-calculator%3Amaster

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if I run `yarn cover` locally, I see the coverage report and the clove file in `coverage/lcov.info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath` is deprecated and that the replacement is `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths`. With that little change everything is reporting as expected.

Comment: I'm working with an older version and I never would have thought to verify that syntax if not for this.